# Reenvio formulario despues de un registro

Tags: php

Alguien sabe que método utilizar cuando sale reenvio de formulario, se que con

### `header('Location: index.php');`

lo puedo solucionar, pero no estaría buscando esa manera. Ya que el registro lo hago mediante un popup desde la misma page. Algún otro método que me destruya los datos después del registro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

proba con un:

```
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```